# Кастомизация Exception и окна вывода ошибки C#

Tags: c#, winforms

У меня возник вопрос, как я могу кастомизировать класс Exception и создать свою форму вывода ошибки.
Я создал такой класс, я не до конца разобрался как можно сделать так, что бы когда выскакивало исключение, оно отображалось в моей форме, которую создал. В данный момент,  форма выскакивает, но после ее закрытия выскакивает стандартное окно исключения

```
internal class Error : ApplicationException
{
    private readonly string PathLog = Application.StartupPath;

    public Error(string message, Exception innerException) : base(message, innerException)
    {
        using (ExceptionForm Excep = new(message, innerException))
        {
            Excep.ShowDialog();
        }
        WriteLog($"[{message}] > {innerException.Message}");
    }

    public async void WriteLog(string message)
    {
        using StreamWriter stream = new($"{PathLog}\\syslog.txt", true, Encoding.UTF8);
        await stream.WriteLineAsync(GetMessageTime(message));
    }

    private static string GetMessageTime(string message)
    {
        return $"{DateTime.Now:G} | {message}";
    }

    public Error(string message) : base(message) { }

    public Error() { }
}
```

Comment: Зачем вам тут `кастомизировать класс Exception`? Вам достаточно подписаться на [события](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5762806), которое возникают при ошибке и на его основе строить логику.

Comment: [ApplicationException](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.applicationexception?view=net-5.0) (читайте ремарку) не рекомендуется к применению. Наследуйте свой класс от `Exception`.

Comment: Согласно [правилам именования](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/names-of-classes-structs-and-interfaces) ваш класс должен называться `ErrorException`.

Comment: Теперь по коду. Ловите и обрабатывайте исключения с помощью `try-catch`, тогда не будет выскакивать стандартное окно. И покажите, что вы делаете, чтобы отображать его в своём окне.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov К примеру, в котором я хочу его использовать.У меня есть класс который подгружает список из csv файла, контроль ошибок хочу сделать что бы оповестить пользователя о наличие пути, правильного формата, не пуст ли он и т.д

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Спасибо, я разобрался :D